# How to simulate a iid process in R language?

Tags: r, statistics

Im new to statictics and received below question that need to be answered in R language:

Simulate an i.i.d process {Xt}t=1,···,n following standard normal Xt ∼ Normal(0,1) with
sample size n = 1000 and simulation time N = 500. Compute the sample mean  ̄X(1),··· ,  ̄X(N),
where  ̄X(i) is the sample mean from the i-th simulation. Plot the histogram for  ̄X(1),··· ,  ̄X(N).

my thought is:

1. as sample size n=1000, then I should

> set.seed(1) # Setting a seed
> X1 <- rnorm(1000) # Simulating X1

2. to compute the sample mean of X1-XN

> result.mean <- mean(x1)

3. plot the histogram for mean X1-XN

> plot(result.mean, type = 'h')

However I'm not sure what to do with the simulation time N = 500? the plot i generated is just 1 bar histogram, so I'm pretty sure the simulation time should be used.

what is the purpose of simulation here? and if my thought correct in the case of iid? thank you

Comment: Looks like a homework question, right? What have you tried? On the last part, how about going into the R console and typing `?plot` and look up type. "l" would be a line. "h" is histogram. You could set up a data frame with the random numbers. I don't know if you need a seed. Then the mean values of each column can be the values to plot.

Comment: Hi @markhogue, thanks for the heads up, yes my plot type is not echoing with the question. i have tried the code above, im just not sure what's the purpose of the simulation time value

Comment: Your assignment is _"Compute the sample mean ̄X(1),··· , ̄X(N), where ̄X(i) is the sample mean from the i-th simulation,"_ which means you need to run `rnorm(n)` `N` times, where n = 1000 and N = 500. Try `replicate`.

Answer (score 0):

Using randomized numbers from a normal distribution, the base (`stats`) r code is rnorm, with default values having a mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1. We get 500 samples from this. Then, take the mean of a vector of those 1000 numbers. We repeat that with `replicate` 1000 times and throw the result into a histogram.

```
hist(replicate(500, mean(rnorm(1000)), simplify = "vector"))
```

[image]